# Scripting the latest month in the data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, date, aggregate-functions

In the following view,instead of specifying the actual dates in the where condition,I want sql server to recognize June and May as the latest month and the (latest month-1) as the view gets refreshed on a monthly basis and so does latest month and (latest month -1).

PS:- The latest Report month is June in the table

```
SELECT (A.[First Name])
    ,A.[Last Name]
    ,A.[Report Month]
FROM (
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [First Name]
            ,[Last Name]
            ,[Report Month]
            ,[Bill To Code]
            ,[Region]
            ,[Area]


        FROM dbo.Data
        WHERE (
                [Report Month] BETWEEN '2015-06-01'
                    AND '2015-06-30'
                AND [FTE Status] = 'Inactive'
                )
        ) A INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT [First Name]
            ,[Last Name]
            ,[Report Month]
            ,[Bill To Code]
            ,[Region]
            ,[Area]


        FROM dbo.Data
        WHERE (
                [Report Month] BETWEEN '2015-05-01'
                    AND '2015-05-31'
                AND [FTE Status] = 'Active'
                )
        ) B ON A.[First Name] = B.[First Name]
        AND A.[Last Name] = B.[Last Name]
    )
```

Thank you,just learnt how to format better in SO.Thanks to Sean.Learning from my mistakes guys..:)

Comment: What part(s) are you having problems with? You don't really have a question here.

Comment: Report_month is a column in your table? And it doesn't contain a month but a date? And the data is not up-to-date? So the last month may not yet be in the table? But you want to get the last month from that table nonetheless? Sorry, this is too confusing to make sense of.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys,Report month is a column in my table.Its a date field,Yes,the latest data in the table is June 2015.In the future when the table gets updated,the values might not be recent,hence i have to get sql server to read the latest month

Comment: What does that last query have to do with this? You have to realize we can't see your screen and the only thing we know about what you want to do is what you post...which at this point isn't much. Help us understand what you want to do because I am guessing it is pretty easy once we understand.

Comment: select *
from dbo.Data
where 
([Report Month] between '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-31' and [FTE Status]='Active')

Comment: Sorry guys,Just edited the post to make it more clear.I hope i'm sending my message across

Comment: Notice that every answer is a completely different concept than the others? This is because you didn't provide a clear question. I would suggest you take a look at this article for examples of a better way to post questions in the future. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sorry Sean,I'm new to SO.I'm trying to paste the long code im working and edit the post and make it better..How do i do it?

Comment: Data? Is this really your table name? And you are using DISTINCT because there can be duplicates in the table? And you rely on 'John Smith' being a unique identifier for a person? All this including the column called month but not containing a month tells me that it might be good to redesign your database.

Comment: Thorsten,It is a test table created on a local host.The names and stuff would be changed once we create the tables in the actual server.And true,there is no unique identifier in the table to use.I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: Hi, sorry, all I can say is: look for entities. A user identified by some ID, a bill, a bill position, etc. Then build your tables accordingly. Most tables do have something that uniquely identifies a record (A user ID, a bill number, a bill number plus an item number, ...). Make use of the relational model in an RDBMS.

Comment: Your query looks strange. (Queries with DISTINCT are usually suspicious, as DISTINCT is only rarely needed in a well-formed database.) You select a user's bills for the two months and combine *all* their bills from May with *all* their bills from June. So if a user X has bills A and B in May and bills C and D in June (including duplicates which you remove, where I wonder why should there be two bills A in May for one user), you end up with record pairs AC, AD, BC, and BD...

Comment: ... And then at last you show user X with the C date twice and with the D date twice (e.g.: `John Smith 2015-06-01, John Smith 2015-06-01, John Smith 2015-06-20, John Smith 2015-06-20`). This just doesn't look like a desired result.

Comment: Thorsten,Thanks for your input.I understand your points and agree they are the best practice,but i created the table using the excel file given to me by my boss.the excel file obviously has a lot of duplicates and hence they came in sql server too.Regarding the unique identifier,I want to share a screenshot of all the columns of my table.I'm not sure if i can do it here..I'll answer my question and tag you!

Comment: Can't Post images ,need atleast 10 reputation..:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence i should write some function so that sql server reads the start
>   and end date of the latest month in the data set.

You say you need to read the start and end date, but if what you really need is just to get all the data that is in the latest month in your table, then this will do it:

```
select *
from dbo.Data
where DATEDIFF(month,[Report Month],(SELECT MAX([Report Month] FROM dbo.Data))=0
and [FTE Status]='Active'
```

Comment: Thank you Tab,it is what I was looking for

Comment: Your logic works like a charm @Tab..Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped.   You can mark this question as answered by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.  : )

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT MAX(MONTH(Report_Month))
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YEAR(Report_Month)
HAVING YEAR(Report_Month) = MAX(YEAR(Report_Month))
```

Comment: This is what you read from the request? That the OP wants a list of all months that were the last month in some year? Well, given that I don't understand the request at all you may even be right, but I have my doubts :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I think all of the confusion got to me. I've corrected my answer to what I think* might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your rather vague question, I think this is what you are looking for.

This will return the first and last day for the max date in YourTable.

```
;with cte as (
  select convert(date,left(convert(varchar,Max(Report_Month),112),6) + '01') startDate,
         month(Max(Report_Month)) n
  from YourTable
  union all
  select dateadd(month,n,convert(date,convert(varchar,year(startDate)) + '0101')) startDate,
        (n+1) n
  from cte
  where n < month(startDate) 
)
select startdate, dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,startdate)) enddate
from cte
```